# Disk usage in Mac terminal not working with --max-depth

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I want to see my **disk usage** for a specific folder with a pre-set **maximum depth**. On Linux, the command is

```
$ du -h --max-depth 1
```

On macOS Mojave (10.14.5) with bash version `3.2.57(1)-release`, this is not working. I also tried

```
$ du -hd1
```

as described [here](https://ma.ttias.be/du-max-depth-alternative-mac-osx/), also not working. The terminal output is:

```
usage: du [-H | -L | -P] [-a | -s | -d depth] [-c] [-h | -k | -m | -g] [-x] [-I mask] [file ...]
```

What is the best solution?

Comment: Can you edit your post with these commands and their output ? `type -a du` and `declare -f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [fd0](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362201/disk-usage-in-mac-terminal-not-working-with-max-depth?noredirect=1#comment480720_362201), I was able to resolve the problem. The output

```
$ type -a du
du is aliased to 'du -sh'
du is /usr/bin/du
```

makes clear that the command `du` was aliased to `du -sh`. By removing this line from my `.bash_profile`, everything works as it should. The solution e.g. by [PeterVP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/362207/162606) works perfectly fine:

```
$ du -h -d 1
```

Answer (score 6):

```
du -h -d 1
```

seems to work on my Mac